# Can not find Transform -> affect only origins anywhere?

Tags: transforms, origin, transform-orientation

I cannot find the affect only origin for transformation anywhere check the image below -

 
[image]

I am using blender version - 2.93.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably in *Edit* mode, you need to switch to *Object* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , I am new to blender and didn't notice i was in edit mode , i even watched 30 min of videos and read manual on how to change origin but couldn't find the option.