# Can't use the grab (G) to move an object

Tags: modeling

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, when I press <kbd>G</kbd> I can't move the object automatically anymore, also when I press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate it, I can't rotate the object automatically anymore without clicking it with the mouse.

I hope you can help me, I don't have this issue on my other computer with Blender!

Comment: Have you somehow disabled the keybinds, or set them to something else by accident? If resetting the keybinds doesn't work, I would suggest restarting the app.

Comment: Can you transform the object using the Transform section in the Item tab of the 'N'  panel of the 3D View? Maybe the object has been mad un-selectable in the viewport?

Comment: Have you enabled "affect origins only" accidentally? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244987/107598

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by going to the tool tab after pressing the <kbd>N</kbd> key, make sure your active tool is the move tool by pressing the <kbd>G</kbd> key. Under the Active Tool setting there is drag, select Active Tool. This should move your selected objects wherever your cursor is